# Enabling loadFromRemoteSources via Visual Studio 2010 GUI

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Today I met an error while trying to generate a Silverlight project from VS2010.
The error concerned a reference to a DLL file located on a remote computer.
The error message contained the following link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890038(VS.100).aspx

The main content of the MSDN web page did not help me because my DLL file was already unblocked.
But I have got help from comments in the bottom of the page.
I needed to include the following tag into a VS2010 file named "devenv.exe.config" :

```
<runtime>
   <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" /> <!-- The tag I have included. -->
 ...
```

I am wondering if there is way to enabled the loadFromRemoteSources variable via the VS2010 GUI.